# How to use np.where with multiple conditions including "or"?

Tags: python, numpy, conditional-statements, finance

I can't figure out how to use `np.where` in a way that np applies the transformation if either condition is met.

I tried just throwing in an or with some parentheses but I really am not sure what I'm doing here. I've seen people successfully pull this off with an `&`, but this doesn't work with `or`.

```
for value in sp500['vix10dFuture']:

value =  np.where(sp500['vix'].shift(-30) >= sp500['vix'] or  16, 1, 0)

sp500['vix30dFuture'] = value
```

I want to create a binary target where if a value is greater than 16 OR greater than the initial past value, the value is 1. Otherwise, the value is zero. I'm getting a

```
ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

error instead.

Comment: Use `|` instead of `or` and make multiple comparison. e.g. `(series_a >= series_b) | (series_a > 16)`

Comment: `or` is a Python scalar test, and generally not useful with numpy arrays.  That's why you get that error.  `|` and `&` (logical or and and) can be used to combine boolean arrays. But what operator order.  Put `()` around comparisons to they operate first.  Focus on constructing the boolean condition array first; passing that to `where` is a last-minute step.